# Jest not generating values correctly using crypto

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, cryptojs

I made a function to generate a complex password using window.crypto lib, this work perfectly and return values like `jQzPN%c@tr71ie6Dt^C8`.
Here is my function :

```
const genPwd = (length: number): string => {
  const regex = /^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,}$/;
  const charset =
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789~!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}]|:;<,>.?/';
  let result = '';
  let values = new Uint32Array(length);
  window.crypto.getRandomValues(values);
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += charset[values[i] % charset.length];
  }
  if (!regex.test(result)) {
    console.log('result', result);
    return genPwd(length);
  } else {
    return result;
  }
};
```

But when I try to test this function using Jest, it falls everytime in the last condition because it doesn't match the regex, the console.log shows "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", like nothing is generating correctly, so it doesn't match the regex and looping.

Here is my test :

```
it('should generate a x length password', () => {
  const mGetRandomValues = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(new Uint32Array(20));
  Object.defineProperty(globalThis, 'crypto', {
    value: { getRandomValues: mGetRandomValues },
  });
  const valueToConvert = utils.genPwd(20);
  const valueToFind = 20;
  expect(valueToConvert).toHaveLength(valueToFind);
  expect(mGetRandomValues).toBeCalledWith(new Uint32Array(valueToFind));
});
```

Does anyone have a solution ?

I have no idea about this issue